# instance method 'connect:' not found (return type defaults to 'id'

Tags: objective-c, xmpp

I am having a warning from Xcode instance method 'connect:' not found (return type defaults to 'id').

i'm still new at programming and following an old tutorial on xmpp messaging.
here is my code:

AppDelegate.h

```
`#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "XMPP.h"


@class ViewController;

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject {
    UIWindow *window;
    ViewController *viewController;
    XMPPStream *xmppStream;
    NSString *password;
    BOOL isOpen;
}//UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>




@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet ViewController *viewController;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) XMPPStream *xmppStream;
- (BOOL) connect;
- (void) disconnect;


@end
`
```

and

Apdelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface AppDelegate()


- (void) setupStream;
-(void) goOnline;
- (void) goOffline;

@end


@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize xmppStream;
@synthesize window;
@synthesize viewController;


- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self disconnect]; // not sure, maybe leave it open


    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self connect]; // also not sure, verify the top

    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self connect];
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}



- (void)setupStream {
    xmppStream = [[XMPPStream alloc] init];
    [xmppStream addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
}

-(void)goOnline {
    XMPPPresence *presence= [XMPPPresence presence];
    [[self xmppStream] sendElement:presence];
}

- (void)goOffline {
    XMPPPresence *presence = [XMPPPresence presenceWithType:@"unavailable"];
    [[self xmppStream] sendElement:presence];
}


- (BOOL)connect {

    [self setupStream];

    NSString *jabberID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"userID"];
    NSString *myPassword = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"userPassword"];

    if (![xmppStream isDisconnected]) {
        return YES;
    }


    if (jabberID == nil || myPassword == nil) {

        return NO;
    }

    [xmppStream setMyJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:jabberID]];
    password = myPassword;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![xmppStream connect:&error])
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                            message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Can't connect to server %@", [error localizedDescription]]
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
        [alertView release];


        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}

-(void) disconnect {
    [self goOffline];
    [xmppStream disconnect];

}


@end
```

the issue I am having is with if (![xmppStream connect:&error])

Comment: That's because `connect:` is not part of the [`XMPPStream`'s interface](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/blob/master/Core/XMPPStream.h). Am I missing something?

Comment: yes it seems so :(, i am following the below mentioned tutorial: [link](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-xmpp-integration/), it is kind of outdated, any idea of what to use instead? i tried to use isConnected instead, but it gave me the same error.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to use:

```
if (![xmppStream connectWithTimeout:XMPPStreamTimeoutNone error:&error])
```

found it in the XMPP sample